# Windows 11 / Arm64 - USB Serial Driver

Tags: driver, usbserial, windows-11

Good day.  We currently deploy our own drivers for Windows 32bit and 64bit.  I am trying to update the USBSerial driver to work on Windows 11 ARM.  Based on the documentation i am finding, i thought it would be as simple as adding the ARM64 block, but it will not work.

Added this up at the top

```
[Manufacturer] 
%MFGNAME%=DeviceList, NTamd64, NTarm64
```

And then i added this block

```
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;  ARM64
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[DriverInstall.NTarm64] 
include=mdmcpq.inf
CopyFiles=FakeModemCopyFileSection
AddReg=DriverInstall.NTarm64.AddReg 


[DriverInstall.NTarm64.AddReg] 
HKR,,DevLoader,,*ntkern 
HKR,,EnumPropPages32,,"MsPorts.dll,SerialPortPropPageProvider" 

[DriverInstall.NTarm64.Services] 
AddService=usbser, 0x00000002, DriverService.NTarm64

[DriverService.NTarm64] 
DisplayName=%SERVICE% 
ServiceType=1
StartType=3
ErrorControl=1
ServiceBinary=%12%\%DRIVERFILENAME%.sys
```

and here is my PIC/VID block which is just a copy with the new arm64 (removed the pids/vids for safety)

```
[SourceDisksFiles]
[SourceDisksNames]
[DeviceList]
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall, <listed here>

[DeviceList.NTamd64] 
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall, <listed here>

[DeviceList.NTarm64] 
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall, <listed here>
```

Any other thoughts on what i might be missing for making the driver work?

this is the command i use on the windows 11/arm machine to generate the cat file

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22000.0\x86\inf2cat" /driver:"C:\Users\source\Source" /os:7_X86,7_X64,XP_X86,XP_X64,8_ARM /verbose
```

I don't get any errors and it builds the cat file fine.. but this is still happening when i try to use the driver on my device

[image]

Doesn't seem like there is an easy way to debug this process either.

Thanks